# Why the app auto background refresh?

Tags: ios, background

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable) {

    NSLog(@"Background updates are available for the app.");
}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] ==     UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied)
{
    NSLog(@"The user explicitly disabled background behavior for this app or for the whole system.");
}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted)
{
    NSLog(@"Background updates are unavailable and the user cannot enable them again. For example, this status can occur when parental controls are in effect for the current user.");
}
```

And using this code to check the app status:
The app alway get into UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable, and does not set any for "Background Modes" in capabilities(and info.plist).

Can anyone answer this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `backgroundRefreshStatus` property only mirror's device settings for the current user and is independent of the info.plist modes you set

Comment: I AM didn't set anything for background mode infos both settings and info.plist, last month it is working fine, i don't why.

Comment: I don't get what your issue is. I answered why it goes into the 1. if

Comment: sorry. try reformulating and clarifying your issue